# Can't handle an uploaded file exceeding maxrequestlength

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get a specific error message posted when a user tries to upload a file that exceeds the maxrequestlength of 10MB for my asp:fileupload object. However, adding the onError attribute to my fileupload object, the user does not get the error I want displayed; the page just crashes. Setting customerrors mode to on and setting up a redirect page doesn't work either; the page still crashes. How am I supposed to get the page to display a specific error without crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you check the file length before uploading the file and if it is greater than 10MB;
then throw custom error message.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
        //This value is in bytes. 
        int iMaxFileSize = 2097152; 
        if (Request.ContentLength > iMaxFileSize) 
        { 
             Response.Redirect("Error.aspx"); 
        } 

    }
```

you can also increase the maxRequestLength in your web config.

```
<httpRuntime

executionTimeout="3600"

maxRequestLength="1048576"

useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"

minFreeThreads="8"

minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"

appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
```

May be this could help you:-  [test file size before upload](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileuploadsize.aspx?df=100&forumid=238999&exp=0&select=1293085)

Comment: first you need to hide the custom browse button of file Upload then create your upload button and write click event on that button for validation.

Comment: So then how would the user get the window that allows them to browse through their directory for a file?

Comment: Sorry to ask so many minute details, but when I open the debugger, there is no separation between the button and the text field for the fileupload object. How would I hide the button itself?